# CSS Container/Background Not Showing; Rest of Layout Works

Tags: css, html, background, containers

Here's my issue and I'll do my best to be clear here--
I have a simple website laid out in complete CSS using an external stylesheet.
I have a main container holding all of the elements for the website content; however, they all seem to be working except for the one that holds the actual page text and the `businessbox`. Right now, it's show the main containers background color (green) instead of what it should be (white). I'm positive it is something simple that I overlooked and will probably kick myself later, but thought I'd ask for a second pair of eyes.

Here is what I'm getting and what it should look like. If I'm having problems with this one container, hopefully programming the 3 vertical columns won't be an issue!

SCREENSHOT:

[image]

My stylesheet (style.css):

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */


body {
background: #88b488;
margin: 3%;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#container {
background: #006200;
width: 1020px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
background-image: url(img/BS_header.jpg);
background-repeat:  no-repeat;
background-position:center;
width: 1020px;
height: 322px;
} 


<!-- MENU ITEMS -->
#menu {
background: #25235b;
width: 100%;
z-index: 2;
}

#menu ul, #menu ul ul {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
float: right;
margin-top: 15px;
margin-right: 5px;
}

#menu ul li{
padding: 5px;
position: relative;
float: left;
}

#menu ul a:link, #menu ul a:visited{
display: inline-block;
color: #ffffff;
width: 90px;
padding: 5px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
} 

#menu ul a:hover, #menu ul a:active {
background: #006100;
}

#menu ul ul {
position: absolute;
margin-top: -1px;
right: 0px;
white-space: nowrap;
visibility: hidden;
}

#menu ul li:hover ul li{
    visibility: visible;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #afafaf;
    padding: 0px;
}

<!-- CONTENT -->
#cbox{
width: 1020px;
background-color: #ffffff;
background-image:url(img/content_grad.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#businessbox {
background-color: #006200;
width: 620px;
height: auto;
border-top: 3px solid #afafaf;
margin-top: 30px;
padding: 10px;
margin: 30px auto 0px;
}

.businesstitle {
text-align:center;
font-size: 20px;
color: #ffffff;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-style:italic;
}

.businesstext {
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 14px;
}

#footer {
font-size: 10px;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
padding: 10px;
background: #006100;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Buy Local</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
<div id="header">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hot Deals</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sign Up!</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Resources</a>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
      </ul>
    </div> <!--end of menu-->
</div> <!--end of header-->

<div id="cbox">
    <div id="businessbox">
        <div class="businesstitle">Our BUSINESS OF THE MONTH:</div><br />
        <img src="#" width="150" height="90" style="float: left; padding-right: 10px;"/>
        <div class="businesstext">You could be our next title sponsor and get your business in the spotlight with logo, name, and short blurb about your business.</div>
    </div> <!--end of businessbox-->

</div> <!--end of cbox-->

<div id="footer">
    2013 &copy; Buy Local
</div><!--end of footer-->

</div><!--end of container-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you want `businessbox`to be white then why do you give `background-color: #006200;` to your business class. just change it to white

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got HTML comments in your CSS. The browser is skipping rendering the line next to it so your #cbox and #menu styles are never applied. Remove the `<!-- MENU ITEMS -->` and `<!-- CONTENT -->` comments and this should work fine.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZBmne/1/) for that in action.

Comment: The cbox styles are the styles that are broken — #businessbox is set to be green (#006200).

Comment: **kpeatt** - weird, my menus are working the way I have it. Just my cbox isn't. The business box should be green (and still is like the main container background). Didn't realize the comments were causing the issues--I'll try taking those out (I'm not at the office, but will check it tomorrow morning!)
**Michael**, business box should be okay, just the cbox wasn't working.

Comment: Okay - I got it working; I'm so silly and didnt realize I did that with the comments. Long day and didn't catch the obvious as I said!

It is working now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

OP,

Why are you doing this: `<img src="#" ...` ?

Also, are *any* of your `background-image` urls resolving?

Comment: B/c I don't have the image there yet. Its a placeholder.
The header one is, but the one in the same container I'm having problems with is not.

Comment: Yep, its working now. I used the wrong "comment" formatting. HAHAHAH. Oh my.

Comment: Glad to hear it. If your question has been answered, it's important to mark it so others know that you no longer need help.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said, it was the obvious--used the wrong commenting format and it caused the #cbox attribute to not function correctly.

Thanks for taking your time to help me with my silly problem!

Answer (score 0):

Where you use image or background-image there use `overflow: hidden; height: 1%;` i think will solve your problem.